# How to enable ssh login for _www user?

Tags: ssh, login, apache

In order to deploy files the the apache server running on OS X host I want to ssh/scp to it using the `_www` user.

I do not want to use root because I want to be sure that I always put the files with correct permissions.

The problem is that I am not able to login with `_www`. I did change the password for the account but ssh login still fails after asking me the password two times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_www` user is designed to never have a shell and many of the user attributes needed for ssh to run are missing. Once you log in as any other admin user, you can easily sudo over to user `_www` to get file permissions correct.

```
mac:~ me$ dscl . -read /Users/_www
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000046
NFSHomeDirectory: /Library/WebServer
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 70
RealName:
 World Wide Web Server
RecordName: _www www
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 70
UserShell: /usr/bin/false

mac:~ me$ sudo -u _www -s
Password:
bash-3.2$ id
uid=70(_www) gid=70(_www) groups=70(_www),61(localaccounts),12(everyone)
```

You can compare with a real user to see the missing attributes. If you want to hack, you could try making the NFSHomeDirectory writable and editing the shell - but that would leave all sorts of user files in /Library/Webserver - and your custom mods might get wiped out each update or cause unintended effects down the road.

Any reasons why you don't just create a apache admin user with a UID less than 500 so that [it won't show in the log in screen as a normal user](https://serverfault.com/questions/26297/can-you-set-an-account-for-ssh-only-access-in-mac-os-10-5)?

(or simply use a normal user to ssh in before using sudo to become `_www`)?

It's a lot less work and more secure. `_www` is intentionally placed in a sandboxbox to reduce the chance that web browsing does bad things to a running mac.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. The problem is that I use some other tools for the deployment and these tools are not able to `chown`. Do you know any workaround that will not risk me to break the web server due to file permissions?

Comment: You should be able to make the user you use be in a group appropriate for the existing files - what directories do you deploy to? `_www` has no problems reading files owned by root (or any other user) it's more a `umask`/`chmod` issue than ownership.

Comment: Deployment software, that is unable to `chown`? Really? I think you need to find some better software, personally.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you couldn't ssh directly as _www because the password may not be set, and the shell may be set to `/usr/bin/false`.

Alternatively, you can ssh in as a regular user, and if your user has admin privileges you could do this:

```
(me@local)$ ssh me@myserver
(me@myserver)$ sudo -u _www -s
Password: (type it in)
(_www@myserver)$ whoami
_www
```

I've just done this on both Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Lion. It's great for checking that permissions are setup correctly.